# ASP AJAX Show Div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

What I want is after inserting a comment, I want to call an jquery to fade in the message telling the user if the insertion was successfull or not. How can be is done. I now that in the jquery I want to use the fade in effect but I don't know how to link these two together. The server side script is onClick of the button

Currently what I have is this

```
            bool result = true
            if (result)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous communication via JavaScript, it has nothing to do with fades or other transitions. You should look into a JavaScript library like jQuery to handle this.

Comment: Oh sorry. You're right I wanted to mention jquery not ajax... How can I link these two.

Comment: I have updated my answer check it.

Comment: @Thomas: that I know. What I don't know is how in the server side script I do some functions: Inserting a record and show a message after if it was successfull or not

Answer (score 0):

You never exactly say whether you're using asp classic or asp.net, but we can make a guess based on part of your question (now tagged better).  Here's the key phrase:

> The server side script is onClick of the button

That tells me you're likely using asp.net. It also tells me that you're doing a full postback to your server code.  That means that when you click the button, the DOM currently loaded in your browser is destroyed, and an entirely new page is retrieved from the server. This is how asp.net events work.  And that means that way you call your jQuery effect to load after the result is the use the [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) on the page to [register your javascript to run on startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) (load) of the page.